# Retrive data from two tables which have One-to-many relation each other using RedBean php

Tags: php, laravel-4, orm, many-to-many, redbean

Here is the stucture of my tables;

```
    stu_details
    -----------
    id INT PK AI
    f_name VARCAHR(45)
    l_name VARCHAR(45)
    dob VARCHAR(45)

    subject
    ----------
    id INT PK AI
    sub_name VARCHAR(45)
    day VARCHAR(45)

    subject_has_stu_details(associative table)
    -----------------------------------------
    id INT PK AI
    subject_id INT FK (frm subject table)
    stu_details_id INT FK (frm stu_details table)
```

My Persistent Classes;

```
public class SubjectHasStuDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private StuDetails stuDetails;
     private Subject subject;

    public SubjectHasStuDetails() {
    }
    //getters & setters......
}

public class StuDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String FName;
     private String LName;
     private String dob;
     private Set subjectHasStuDetailses = new HashSet();

    public StuDetails() {
    }
    //getters & setters......
}

public class Subject  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String subName;
     private String day;
     private Set subjectHasStuDetailses = new HashSet();
     private Set teachers = new HashSet();

    public Subject() {
    }

    //getters & setters......
}
```

Using hibernate with javaEE I can retrive data like below;
(I'm trying to get all the subjects related to the student)

```
      Session ss = util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
       String student_Name="Jhon"; 
        List<SubjectHasStuDetails> stu_sub = ss.
            createQuery("FROM SubjectHasStuDetails shs WHERE"
                    + " shs.stuDetails.FName= :nm").
            setParameter("nm", student_Name).list();
    for (SubjectHasStuDetails shs : stu_sub) {

        System.out.println("Name - " + shs.getStuDetails().getFName()
                + "  Subject - " + shs.getSubject().getSubName());
    }
```

here is my code for redbean;

```
   $subject_table = R::findAll('subject');
    foreach ($subject_table as $subject) {
        echo $subject->id;
        foreach ($subject->sharedTable as $sub) {
            echo $sub->sub_name;
        }
    }
```

But In RedBean I didnt get exact picture of retriving data even 
after reffering the documentation. Any sugessions are appreciable.